# Using jquery, How can i reference this span object?

Tags: jquery, selector

I have the following html:

```
  <span id="enterStreamName" style="display:none">
       <input type="text" id='Stream' class="fullRowTextBox" value="" name="Stream" />
       <button class="SaveStreamButton">Save</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <button class="CancelStreamButton">Cancel</button>
  </span>

  <span class="statusHeading"></span>
```

and i can't figure out how to reference the "statusHeading" span from a click event on "CancelStreamButton"

i have tried:

```
 .find(), .next(), siblings()
```

but none seem to work

I have multiple element with class statusHeading so i need to make sure i refer to only this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to target it.

```
$('.CancelStreamButton').parent().next();
```

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljmng/2/)***

So, on click event of the button, it would be

```
$(this).parent().next();
```

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljmng/3/)***

But again since you have a class assuming there are no duplicate spans with the same class, you could directly use `$('span.statusHeading')`

Comment: I updated the question to verify that i do have multiple statusHeadings and i only want to refer to this one so can't just use the second option in your answer

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the id as a starting point:

```
$('#enterStreamName + .statusHeading')
```

Comment: @leora The + symbol is the CSS selector for adjacent sibling, so jQuery will interpret this as a selector for an element with class "statusHeading" that immediately follows an element with id of "enterStreamName".

Answer (score -1):

Since you updated the question here's my updated answer. I'm going to assume adding an `ID` is not an option to the span tag you're trying to access. Instead you can traverse the index of the span tags. Doesn't matter what's in between the span tags, by using the `eq()` traverse function of jQuery you should be able to target any of them.

```
$('.CancelStreamButton').on('click', function(event){
   //eq traverses the index of the span tags
   $('.statusHeading').eq(1).css('border','1px solid red');
});
```

Updated Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/CM3s3/1/

Comment: see updated questoin.  i have multiple items with statusHeading and i need to refer to just this one.

Comment: Just add an `ID` to the span tag then. If that's not an option then you are going to have to traverse the DOM.